# ProximityAlert Not Working on EMulator API level 4.2

Tags: android, emulation

I am trying to use code on follwing link. This is example of proximity based notification.

I am running following code on 4.2 but it is not working on emulator of API level 17 but it s working.

[http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-proximity-alerts-tutorial.htmlperfectly fine on API 2.2](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-proximity-alerts-tutorial.htmlperfectly%20fine%20on%20API%202.2)

Comment: * but it is working perfectly fine on API 2.2